# Jacksonで2つ以上の型を持つ配列をパースするには

Tags: java, json, jackson

JavaのJsonパーサJacksonを使って配列をパースするとき普通であれば。以下のようにレスポンスのモデルを作成し、`readValues`を用いてパースできます。

```html
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try{
  ResponseClass response = mapper.readValue(response.toString(), ResponseClass.class);
}(SomeException e){
  }

--------------

//Model class
class ResponseClass{
  public List<SomeType> items;
}

--------------

//Json response
{
  [
     {
        type:"TypeA",
        name:"hoge"
     },
  ........
```

しかし例えばこの配列の要素の型が複数ある場合はどうすればいいのでしょうか。例えば取得するJsonオブジェクトが以下のようなものの場合。

```html
{
  [
    {
      type:"typeA",
      name:"hoge"
    },
    {
      type:"typeB",
      mail:"hoge@hoge.com"
    }
   .......
  ]
{
```

この場合はObjectモデルのListのジェネリクスとフィールド名はどのようにすればいいのでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonArrayに変換したあとで、for文を使ってその要素を調べて特定の要素がある場合で場合分けしてからJsonObjectにパースしました。
他にもいい方法があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

JsonTypeInfoとJsonSubTypesを使うことで一度のパースでobjectに変換できます。

以下のようなクラスの形になります。

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

import java.io.Serializable;

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Hero.SpiderMan.class, name = "spiderMan"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Hero.IronMan.class, name = "ironMan")
})
public abstract class Hero implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1043995422704061066L;

    public static class SpiderMan extends Hero {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3086739225292748194L;

        private String realmName;

        public String getRealmName() {
            return realmName;
        }

        public void setRealmName(String realmName) {
            this.realmName = realmName;
        }
    }

    public static class IronMan extends Hero {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -235208732212962783L;

        private String height;

        public String getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(String height) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }
}
```

JsonTypeInfoでどうやってクラスを判別するか　という情報をJsonに埋め込みます。
僕の書いたコードの場合だと、 type というフィールドをプロパティとして埋め込みます。
また、JsonSubTyoesは実際のクラスを記述します。

以下はテストしたコード

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class HeroTest {
    private static final String SERIALIZED_JSON = "{\"heroes\":[{\"type\":\"spiderMan\",\"realmName\":\"Peter Benjamin Parker\"},{\"type\":\"ironMan\",\"height\":\"6'1\\\"; (in armor) 6'6\\\"\"}]}";

    @Test
    public void shouldBeSerialized() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Hero.SpiderMan spiderMan = new Hero.SpiderMan();
        spiderMan.setRealmName("Peter Benjamin Parker");

        Hero.IronMan ironMan = new Hero.IronMan();
        ironMan.setHeight("6'1\"; (in armor) 6'6\"");

        List<Hero> heros = new LinkedList<>();
        heros.add(spiderMan);
        heros.add(ironMan);

        Mervel mervel = new Mervel();
        mervel.setHeroes(heros);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String serialized = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mervel);

        assert SERIALIZED_JSON.equals(serialized);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeObject() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Mervel mervel = objectMapper.readValue(SERIALIZED_JSON, Mervel.class);

        for (Hero hero : mervel.heroes) {

            if (hero instanceof Hero.SpiderMan) {
                System.out.println("I am spider man. Real name is " +((Hero.SpiderMan) hero).getRealmName());
            } else if (hero instanceof Hero.IronMan) {
                System.out.println("I am Iron man. Height is " +((Hero.IronMan) hero).getHeight());
            } else {
                System.err.println("An error occurred... :(");
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Mervel implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5640686224279032240L;

        private List<Hero> heroes;

        public List<Hero> getHeroes() {
            return heroes;
        }

        public void setHeroes(List<Hero> heroes) {
            this.heroes = heroes;
        }
    }
}
```